# IE on Windows 7 not saving files to disk

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, download

I am running Win 7 Build 7100. Since I restored this system I am facing peculiar issues - all effectively rendering this system unusable.
The biggest peeve is:
Any file downloaded from IE is never saved to disk. IE shows the entire download progress bar and at the end of download, no file is saved anywhere on the disk!

Comment: I am running as an administrator.

Comment: You've tried telling IE to save the file to a neutral location (eg C:\temp) and it still doesn't appear?!

Comment: What happened and how did you restore the system?

Answer (score 1):

OK, so after a few hours of getting my hair pulled out, I located the culprit. Spyware Doctor from "Google Pack"

Uninstalled it and problem solved! Even AVG is working now!

1. I had installed Google Earth
2. Google Earth installs via Google Pack
3. Google Pack installs Spyware Doctor if you aren't paying attention
4. Spyware Doctor basically polices all the file operations for all the applications it can register itself onto.

For further clarification: 
Symptoms of the problem (the system had AVG 8.5, Windows Defender and Spyware Doctor installed) The moment Spyware Doctor installed, AVG was effectively neutered. AVG was simply contributing to poor system performance by eating up CPU and Memory.

Win7 unable to turn on AVG. It could turn on Spyware Doctor and WinDefender.
IE and Firefox 3.5 were unable to save any downloaded files. Folders were perfectly writable.
All file operations took ages. Opening a file, saving a file, closing a file.
A scan using ProcessMonitor revealed Spyware Doctor as the culprit. Uninstall Spyware Doctor and system back to normalcy. Now to get WinDefender out so that I can reclaim some cycles.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the target directory isn't marked as read-only.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have access to that location.  If you did a restore your rights may have gotten messed up.

Further, if this system was domain'd and you removed or changed the domain, good luck.